# Laravel named routes grouping all admin routes

Tags: php, laravel

i just want to group all my admin routes in my laravel. I'm a beginner in laravel and i want to synchronize all my admin routes in one group, my question is, why i cant put the post route inside the group of my admin routes?

Here is my routes:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin::', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('login', [
        'as' => 'login',
        'uses' => 'admin\AdminLoginController@index'
    ]);

    Route::post('login', 'admin\AdminLoginController@auth')->name('admin.login');

});
```

my above code was returning error , where laravel says admin.login route doesn't exist. Then i tried to put the post route outside the group and it works. Why?. 
Here is the code where returns no error:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin::', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('login', [
        'as' => 'login',
        'uses' => 'admin\AdminLoginController@index'
    ]);


});

Route::post('login', 'admin\AdminLoginController@auth')->name('admin.login');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `as` in your route group and it's `admin::` and you may link to `admin.`

Now it goes to `admin::login` and you need `admin.login`

Comment: thank you very much.. now i figured it out how to use this route name list

Comment: If you want to know your route name use command : `php artisan route:list`..good luck @JcJohn